# Does the sum of $1/a_n$ diverge if and only if $a_n=n^{1+o(1)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I was wondering when exactly the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{a_n}\quad\text{with $a_n>0$}$$

diverges, and I came up with the following guess: this happens exactly when $a_n=n^{1+o(1)}$ (i.e. exactly when $a_n$ grows slower than $n^\alpha$ for every $\alpha>1$). Is this correct?

If not, is there some other "Landau notation statement" that does the trick?

Comment: Counterexamples: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569303/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2563446/42969. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2982094/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Awesome, thanks. Do you think there is some "easy Landau way" to denote exactly those series that diverge?

Comment: I don't think so. One reason is that for each divergent series there is another series with “significantly smaller terms” which still diverges: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388898/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452053/42969.

Comment: You should probably add the assumption all $a_n$ are the same sign for sufficiently large $n$, otherwise there are obvious alternating counterexamples such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory%27s_series).